# Where to find complete Kali image for docker with all the tools?

Tags: kali-linux, tools, docker

As of now, I am using Windows 10 & I want to run kali Linux on Docker. For that, I took the copy from the kali official site [Here](https://www.kali.org/news/official-kali-linux-docker-images/)

But after running I found it's just a base OS it doesn't contain all the tools for which kali is famous,  it's not a full flash copy.
So I want a complete kali image for the docker run where I can find the complete kali with all the tools copy for the docker.

**Solved** Listed metapackages using & install

> **apt-get update && apt-cache search kali-linux**

> **kali-linux-arm** - Kali Linux ARM system
>
> **kali-linux-core** - Kali Linux base system
>
> **kali-linux-default** - Kali Linux default system
>
> **kali-linux-everything** - Everything in Kali    Linux
>
> **kali-linux-large** - Kali Linux large system
>
> **kali-linux-nethunter** - Kali Linux NetHunter tools

Comment: Install whatever tools you need? `apt` should work in your docker image.

Comment: Yes... But I am looking for a complete image with all the tools already installed.

Comment: I used "apt-get update && apt-cache search kali-linux" to list available meta packages for docker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Kali Linux Metapackages](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-metapackages/) after setting up a [Kali Linux Docker Image](https://www.kali.org/news/official-kali-linux-docker-images/). In 2019.3 there was a [Major Metapackage Makeover](https://www.kali.org/news/major-metapackage-makeover/), changing the names. To combine this information:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install kali-linux-large
```

> Previously, **kali-linux-full** was the default metapackage, which has
> been renamed to **kali-linux-large** with a redirect put in place.

> When you [download](http://www.kali.org/downloads/) a Kali Linux ISO, you are essentially
> downloading an installation that has the **kali-linux-full**
> metapackage installed. This package includes all of the tools you are
> familiar with in Kali.
>
> Installation Size: 9.0 GB

```
apt-get update && apt-get install kali-linux-everything
```

> Depending on how you use Kali will determine which metapackage would
> suit you best. This is the power of metapackages. For example:
>
> - If you want a core set of tools, stick with **kali-linux-default** (designed for assessments that are straightforward ).
> - If you want a more general and wider range of tools, select **kali-linux-large** (useful if Internet access is permitted but slow).
> - If you want to be prepared for anything, go with **kali-linux-everything** (great if you are going to be doing
>   air-gap/offline work)

> In order to keep our ISO sizes reasonable, we are unable to include
> every single tool that we package for Kali and there are a number of
> tools that are not able to be used depending on hardware, such as
> various GPU tools. If you want to install every available Kali Linux
> package, you can install the **kali-linux-all** metapackage.
>
> Installation Size: 15 GB

Comment: Thanks for your time but I am getting an error "Unable to locate package kali-linux-full" when trying for kali-linux-full & all its not working for docker image.

Comment: Then what you get with `apt-get update && apt-cache search kali-linux`?

Comment: Hit:1 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
kali-linux-arm - Kali Linux ARM system
kali-linux-core - Kali Linux base system
kali-linux-default - Kali Linux default system
kali-linux-everything - Everything in Kali Linux
kali-linux-large - Kali Linux large system
kali-linux-nethunter - Kali Linux NetHunter tools

Comment: Yes. Use those metapackages as applicable to you.

Comment: I found a reason for this and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could have easily given extra +1 for *Installation Size*